# TinyMCE Removing HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I'm writing contents that has example HTML tags in it.

I've already tried all these attributes:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // ...
       cleanup: false,
       cleanup_on_startup: false,
       verify_html: false,
       extended_valid_elements : '*[*]',
});
```

After saving, everything is OK:
[image: After Saving]

But when I reopen it, TinyMCE deletes all the HTML tags in my text:
[image: reopen]

Comment: verify_html: false, what happens when you change it to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the content being stored in your database?

If you want to use a code example that includes HTML, you must use HTML entities for your < and >. If you don't do this, it will be interpreted as actual HTML.

```
&lt;title&gt;Example Title&lt;/title&gt;
```

Also, have you looked into TinyMCE's Code Sample plugin to show code examples?
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/codesample/